# How can I know from which IP an email in Marketing cloud was sent?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sap, ip, jobid

How can I know from which IP an email (for which I have the Job ID) was sent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you send yourself an email to a GMAIL address, you can select "Show Original" on the message & it will show you the SPF details from the email. *(ie SPF:    PASS with IP 13.110.14.214)*[image: google message settings]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you want to just test your SAP configuration, all you need is to have an email sent to your inbox, you can see the sender IP in the message header. It depends on your email client how you get there, just google for how your email tool lets you view the email source code.

Look for a line like "designates xxx.yyy.zz.123 as permitted sender" in the message header to find the sender ip.

If you do NOT have the email in your inbox (yet), but want to investigate out about a past sendout, then do the following.

IP(s) is / are tied to the Delivery Profile.

Delivery Profile is tied to the Send Classification.

Send Classification can be found in the _Job data view for each sendout.

Find the jobid you're looking for in the sent emails overview.

With that jobid, write an SQL query:

```
SELECT 
jobid, 
SendClassification
FROM 
_job
WHERE jobid = 'your Job Id'
```

This gives you the name of the send classification that was used for that sendout. e.g. "Default Commercial"

You can find this classification in email studio, and see what delivery profile is referenced there.

Now using that send classification / delivery profile, send yourself an email, and go back to the beginning of this post.

There is a logical limit to this of course, you cannot determine if somebody has changed the delivery profile or send classification SINCE the sendout. But since those changes usually are not happening too often, it's a good enough approach in most cases that are not a criminal investigation. :)

Comment: Generally speaking I agree with you on your points, and they also are adequate for 9 out of 10 SFMC clients. But do keep in mind, some high volume senders might have IP pools consisting of multiple IP adresses. There is AFAIK no way of identifying whether an email sent in JobID 1 to SubKey XYZ, on a delivery profile pointing at this IP pool was sent from one IP or the other.

Comment: That is correct and the data view documentation also seems to be aware of this shortcoming, as it states "IPAddress field will always be null". If several IPs are rotating for a delivery profile, there is no way to determine this on a "jobid" level, it would have to be on recipient level, and there is no way for that that I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

We can also have the option to find the IP used for the job using Datorama reports.
Highlighted some details here:
[Total sends per IP address](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/406935/total-sends-per-ip-address/406968#406968)