# Total sends per IP address

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfmcadmin

I'm trying to determine the total send volume for a specific IP address in my Marketing Cloud account, what's the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have intelligence reports enabled in Analytics Builder, you can run the report to find the email send data and the IPs associated with them. You will see an option to select the IP while creating the report as shown in the screenshot.

[image]